# How to access Dynamodb's original JSON elements?

Tags: json, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to test my lambda manually with the following dynamodb event input configured in tests -

Let's call this Json-1

```
 {
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "1",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "New item!"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES",
        "SequenceNumber": "111",
        "SizeBytes": 26
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventSourceARN": eventsourcearn,
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "2",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "OldImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "New item!"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "222",
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SizeBytes": 59,
        "NewImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "This item has changed"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "MODIFY",
      "eventSourceARN": sourcearn,
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "3",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "SizeBytes": 38,
        "SequenceNumber": "333",
        "OldImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "This item has changed"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "REMOVE",
      "eventSourceARN": sourcearn,
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the json of dynamodb items look like this -

Let's call this Json-2

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "RIGHT-aa465568-f4c8-4822-9c38-7563ae0cd37b-1131286033464633.jpg"
  },
  "lines": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "points": {
            "L": [
              {
                "L": [
                  {
                    "N": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "N": "874.5625"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "L": [
                  {
                    "N": "1765.320601851852"
                  },
                  {
                    "N": "809.7800925925926"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "L": [
                  {
                    "N": "3264"
                  },
                  {
                    "N": "740.3703703703704"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "type": {
            "S": "guard"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "modified": {
    "N": "1483483932472"
  },
  "qastatus": {
    "S": "reviewed"
  }
}
```

Using the lambda function below, I can connect to my table. My goal is create a json which elastic search will accept.

```
@Override
    public Object handleRequest(DynamodbEvent dynamodbEvent, Context context) {

        List<DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord> dynamodbStreamRecordlist = dynamodbEvent.getRecords();

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());
        log.info("Whole event - "+dynamodbEvent.toString());

        dynamodbStreamRecordlist.stream().forEach(dynamodbStreamRecord -> {
            if(dynamodbStreamRecord.getEventSource().equalsIgnoreCase("aws:dynamodb")){
                log.info("one record - "+dynamodbStreamRecord.getDynamodb().toString());
                log.info(" getting N from new image "+dynamodbStreamRecord.getDynamodb().getNewImage().toString());

                String tableName = getTableNameFromARN(dynamodbStreamRecord.getEventSourceARN());
                log.info("Table name :"+tableName);

                Map<String, AttributeValue> keys = dynamodbStreamRecord.getDynamodb().getKeys();
                log.info(keys.toString());

                AttributeValue attributeValue = keys.get("Id");
                log.info("Value of N: "+attributeValue.getN());

                Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);


            }
        });

        return dynamodbEvent;
    }
```

The format of a JSON item that elastic search expects is this and this is what I want to map the test input json to-

Let's call this Json-3

```
{
    _index: "bar-guard",
    _type: "bar-guard_type",
    _id: "LEFT-b1939610-442f-4d8d-9991-3ca54685b206-1147042497459511.jpg",
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        @SequenceNumber: "4901800000000019495704485",
        @timestamp: "2017-01-04T02:24:20.560358",
        lines: [{
            points: [[0,
            1222.7129629629628],
            [2242.8252314814818,
            1254.702546296296],
            [4000.0000000000005,
            1276.028935185185]],
            type: "barr"
        }],
        modified: 1483483934697,
        qastatus: "reviewed",
        id: "LEFT-b1939610-442f-4d8d-9991-3ca54685b206-1147042497459511.jpg"
    }
},
```

So what I need is read Json-1 and map it to Json-3. 
However, Json-1 does not seem to be complete i.e. it does not have information that a dynamodb json has - like points and lines in Json-2.

And so, I was trying to get a connection to the original table and then read this additional information of lines and points by using the ID.

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Basically, want to figure out a way to get the actual JSON that dynamodb has and not the one that has attribute types 
How can I get lines and points from json-2 using java? I know we have DocumentClient in javascript but I am looking for something in java.

Also, came across a converter here but doesn't help me- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/dynamodb/converter.js

Is this something that I should use DynamoDBMapper or ScanJavaDocumentAPI for ?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#marshallIntoObjects-java.lang.Class-java.util.List-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-

If yes, I am a little lost how to do that in the code below -

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
                ScanResult result = dynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest);
                for(Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
                    AttributeValue value = item.get("lines");
                    if(value != null){
                        List<AttributeValue> values = value.getL();
                        for(AttributeValue value2 : values){
                            //what next?
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems to work for me.

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
                ScanResult result = dynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest);

                for(Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
                    AttributeValue value = item.get("lines");
                    if(value != null){
                        List<AttributeValue> values = value.getL();

                        for(AttributeValue value2 : values){

                                if(value2.getM() != null)
                            {
                                Map<String, AttributeValue> map = value2.getM();
                                        AttributeValue points = map.get("points");
                                    List<AttributeValue> pointsvalues = points.getL();
                                    if(!pointsvalues.isEmpty()){
                                        for(AttributeValue valueOfPoint : pointsvalues){
                                            List<AttributeValue> pointList = valueOfPoint.getL();
                                            for(AttributeValue valueOfPoint2 : pointList){

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```